# nth-child except if it has a class of "hide"

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-class

I have several item div's with float left so that they appear to be in columns. The user can click on "hide" on any given item, and that adds a ".hide" class to that element, which has display:none css.

**Question:** Is there a way to do `.item:not(.hide):nth-child(2n+2)`?  So that when I have a list of items with one of them having .hide in the middle, the rule still applies and "ignores" that `.hide` item.

Live example in jsbin, http://jsbin.com/ajeqal/edit#javascript,html,live

If you click "hide" in a right-hand column item, the columns get out of order in the sense that the left col should always have a different bg color than the right col. I could move the hidden items to the end of the list, but that's more work.

Html:

```
<style>
  .hide { display:none;}
  .item{ float: left; width: 150px; padding: 5px; background: #ccc;}
  .item:not(.hide):nth-child(2n+1) { background: #999; margin-right:5px }
  .item a { display:inline-block; margin-left: 10px; }
  body { width: 325px; }
  #unhideAll { display: none; clear: left; margin-top: 20px;}
  #container { overflow: auto; }
</style>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <div class="item">item<a href="#">hide</a></div>
  <div class="item">item<a href="#">hide</a></div>
  <div class="item hide">item<a href="#">hide</a></div>
  <div class="item">item<a href="#">hide</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="unhideAll"><a href="#">Unhide All</a></div>
</body>
```

Js:

```
$('#unhideAll').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".hide").removeClass("hide");
  $(this).hide();
});

$(".item a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("hide");
  $("#unhideAll").show();
});
```

Comment: `$('.item:nth-child(2n+2)').not($('.hide'))`

Comment: thanks but, I'm looking to have a rule in CSS that does this for me

Comment: There isn't such a rule, unfortunately. CSS `:nth-child()` doesn't filter that way.

Comment: no. `nth-child` does not combine with other selectors..

Answer (score 1):

There is no css selector to do this. Instead, I'm having to get all the ".hide" elements and appendTo the div that contains them all, essentially moving them all towards the end. if I do this, then they are no longer inter-mixed with the other items.

Answer (score 1):

Nth-child can be counterintuitive when working with a filtered selection of a group.

Use .each() to get around its limitations:

```
var count = 0;
$('.item:not(.hide)').each(function(){
    if ( count++ % 2 == 1 ) $(this).css('background-color','#999')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can say nth-child(odd) instead.

Second, if you want to give it a shot, you could try adding a notHidden class (of which all would have initially), and when add 'hide' remove 'notHidden' and vise-versa. you could then nth-child on .notHidden (in theory).

As others have said the way your are currently doing it won't work as nth-child doesn't consider it removed, and I'm not sure if this will work, but figure it might give you an idea if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.item:not(.hide):nth-of-type(2n+2)`?  I’m going to do some tests to confirm but at first blush it seems like it might work.

Comment: In reply to my own suggestion: no, no it doesn’t work.  Apparently the element names match ahead of the `:not()` qualifier, so you’re selecting the elements themselves and then some are hidden or not.  Curses!